# Changing the color of paragraph and caption text together

Tags: color, captions

I have a question about paragraph text colour and caption text colour.

I want to change the text colour of a part of my paper which has many figures but when I use `\color` command, it only changes the colour of the normal text not the text in the caption of the figures.

Do you have any idea how I can change the text colour of the captions without adding `\color` command to them one by one (I want to modify the colour of a part of my paper, so changing the document default colour is not an option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [caption package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption)

```
% in the preambule
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}

% in the document
\captionsetup{font={color=green}}
```

To change captions only in figures and revert styles back to normal:

```
% in the document
\captionsetup[figure]{font={color=green}}

%\begin{figure}
% figure stuff
%\end{figure}

\clearcaptionsetup{figure}
```

Comment: You mean I should change the caption colour to green at the beginning of the part which I want to modify and then at the end return it back to black using `\captionsetup` command again.

Comment: You can use `\clearcaptionsetup` to revert changes, this requires the setup to be scoped, though. I've update the answer.